# Reading IMAP message content string with groovy

Tags: groovy, imap

Hi i'm working on my grails application in wich i connect to gmail via imap and wait for incoming emails. When an email arrives i need to fetch its content and it suppose to be a string. Then i need to match this string to a regexp to get the most valuable data. The problem is that there is something wrong with this string and it doesn't match my regexp which i tested on usual multiline groovy string and everything worked fine.

```
def processMessage(def imapMessage){
  if(message && message instanceof IMAPMessage){
              def content = message.getContent()
              println 'Content ='+ content
              m_mailContent = content
              println 'm_mailContent is ' + m_mailContent
          }
```

And then

```
def getType(){
       def type = 0 
       if(utility.ParseUtil.matches(m_mailContent, WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP)){
          type = 1
       }else if(utility.ParseUtil.matches(m_mailContent, BNET_REGEXP)){
           type = 2
       }else if(utility.ParseUtil.matches(m_mailContent, QUEUED_REGEXP)){
           type = 3
       }
        return type
    }
But i almost always get type = 0
```

I might need to do something to that string. I have no idea what kind of string i get. When print it everything seems fine. Of course it could be some special characters in it but do i escape them?

```
def WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP = /.*ErrorID:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\.-]*\n.*Time:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\s:]*\n.*URL:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\.]*\n/
```

and a string i get from gmail is something like this

```
ErrorID:  -732861900
Time:     Tue May 24 09:57:54 CEST 2011
URL:      /transnet/organisation.jsp
HttpCode: 500
Error:    class java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
User:     Peter Rådlund (peraa), DHL Express (Sweden) AB
Domain:   DHL Support

Stacktrace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
       at com.memnon.transnet.admin.Account.checkUpdate(Account.java:725)
       at com.memnon.transnet.consignment.ConsignmentDB.updateOrganisation(ConsignmentDB.java:152)
       at org.apache.jsp.transnet.organisation_jsp._jspService(organisation_jsp.java:842)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:334)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.A
```

i try to mach it like this

```
//ParseUtil
static def matches(String str, def regexp){
            def m  = str =~ regexp
            m.find()
        }
```

I hope it's kind of clear now.

Comment: Post your regexs and some sample strings that you're getting back from gmail. Also, try running through ParseUtil matches a sample string, it may be doing a too strict ==~ instead of looser =~ match

Comment: What is `utility.ParseUtil` doing?  What values is `m_mailContent` expected to have? What are `WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP`, `BNET_REGEXP` and `QUEUED_REGEXP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP = /.*ErrorID:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\.-]*\n.*Time:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\s:]*\n.*URL:\s*[A-Za-z\d\/\.]*\n/
```

and a string i get from gmail is something like this

```
ErrorID:  -732861900
Time:     Tue May 24 09:57:54 CEST 2011
URL:      /transnet/organisation.jsp
HttpCode: 500
Error:    class java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
User:     Peter Rådlund (peraa), DHL Express (Sweden) AB
Domain:   DHL Support

Stacktrace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
       at com.memnon.transnet.admin.Account.checkUpdate(Account.java:725)
       at com.memnon.transnet.consignment.ConsignmentDB.updateOrganisation(ConsignmentDB.java:152)
       at org.apache.jsp.transnet.organisation_jsp._jspService(organisation_jsp.java:842)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:334)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.A
```

i try to mach it like this

```
//ParseUtil
static def matches(String str, def regexp){
            def m  = str =~ regexp
            m.find()
        }
```

I hope it's kind of clear now.

I found the answer. In my regex i search for "\n" as line breaker and it did work on java strings i faked to test parsing but in the email body from gmail(which is plain/text content type) i should search for "\r\n". It works  now! I'm so happy!

Thanks for all of your responses guys. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change `WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP` to:

```
def WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP = /(?m)^ErrorID:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$[\n]^Time:\s*([A-Za-z\d\/\s:]*)$[\n]^URL:\s*([A-Za-z\d\/\.]*)$/
```

**edit**

Here is what I have:

```
def message = '''
ErrorID:  -732861900
Time:     Tue May 24 09:57:54 CEST 2011
URL:      /transnet/organisation.jsp
HttpCode: 500
Error:    class java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
User:     Peter Rådlund (peraa), DHL Express (Sweden) AB
Domain:   DHL Support

Stacktrace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied.
       at com.memnon.transnet.admin.Account.checkUpdate(Account.java:725)
       at com.memnon.transnet.consignment.ConsignmentDB.updateOrganisation(ConsignmentDB.java:152)
       at org.apache.jsp.transnet.organisation_jsp._jspService(organisation_jsp.java:842)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:334)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.A'''


def WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP = /(?m)^ErrorID:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$[\n]^Time:\s*([A-Za-z\d\/\s:]*)$[\n]^URL:\s*([A-Za-z\d\/\.]*)$/

static def matches( String str, def regexp ){
  def m  = str =~ regexp
  m.find()
}

println matches( message, WEB_SERVICE_REGEXP )
```

And that prints

```
true
```

Comment: no. it's something with the email string. And i don't know what :(

Comment: you say the email string is _"something like this"_...  Do you have an actual example of an email string that isn't working?

Comment: Look at her question, example email string is right there. As she said, it does work with multi-line """ string (confirmed myself), but it breaks on m.find(), which returns false despite a match being found; thus my downvoted-but-probably-correct-answer below.  Speaking of, downvoter, care to explain? Anonymous downvotes are a bit shady, while explained downvotes are not.

Comment: @virtualeyes yes, I know the string is right there...  I have added an example to my answer.  With the modified regexp, it prints `true`

Comment: why would you ask if you knew it was there? ;-) At any rate, yes, updated regex does work with m.find(), although I'm not sure it will make a difference, as when you manually multi-line the string the original regex also works (albeit, by omitting m.find() and using boolean (str =~ regex) in its place). Curious to know what source of the problem is, regardless...

Comment: Hi it must be something with gmail line breaks. For regexp where i search for \n i get nothing but for regexp where i search only for a specific char sequence i get what i expect. Any ideas what i can use instead of "\n" ? Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
static def matches(String str, def regexp){
            def m  = str =~ regexp
            m.find()
        }
```

To:

```
static def matches(String str, regexp){
       (str =~ regexp)
}
```

Comment: The above absolutely works; m.find() returned false despite a match being returned in str =~ regex line. You want a boolean result, so wrapping like so (str =~ regex) will return exactly what you are looking for. Unwarranted downvote, imo.